erase part of object in sculpt mode
I'm sculpting a face and I don't like the ears so I want to fix it. I want to rebuild the ear from scratch rather than trying to fix the existing ears. How to delete that part (ears) without leaving any holes so I can start to rebuilt it again. Is it possible to do it inside sculpting mode ?

If you're using Blender 4.2 then they just added a bunch of new Sculpt Trim tools. If you're not quite there yet then there's a Line project node and box trim tools in the versions before that. Line project only moves geo, it won't cut the stuff off completely.

Select using lasso or box mask ( turn on mirror to select both ears)


With the ears has been masked , then -> From menu : mask/mask slices and fill holes

Done. Disable 'mask' and apply smooth brush to fix the meshes.

